# Is it possible to combine two (or more) laser beams into one beam with double intensity? What are the caveats of this method?

Tags: optics, laser

Here is a schematic for what I mean:

[image]

Comment: The combined beams are still independent of one another. You can even buy so-called “white” lasers that consist of red, green and blue lasers with their outputs combined via beam splitters and mirrors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but not via total internal reflection, and not without coherent light.

Ray optics is reversible, meaning that if you took the same beamlines and ran light through them backwards, it would also be a valid way for the light to behave.  But if you took a laser and pointed it backwards along where your output beam is now, it would undergo total internal reflection and exit only along the path of input beam 2, with no light exiting along the path of beam 1.

If you did want use a similar geometry, you could;  just don't use total internal reflection.  Specifically, position your beams so that refraction from beam 1 & reflection from beam 2 fall along the same path (your output beam.)  This can be seen as the "reversal" of what would happen if you sent a single beam along your output path, which split when it hit the glass-air interface.

Note, however, that you would need to get the phases of the beams just right so that these two beams end up in phase with each other, and the other beams that would normally be created (reflection of beam 1 and refraction of beam 2) destructively interfere with each other.  This would be tricky without a coherent light source.

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do has a name and it is "beam combining". You can have a look on wikipedia or RP photonics with this keyword.

If the two lasers do not share the same wavelength the idea is to do spectral beam combining. You can use a spectral sensitive beam combiner like a prism or a grating to superpose the two lasers. You will need the wavelengths of the two lasers not to overlap but you can get a good beam combining efficiency.

If the two lasers share the same wavelength and are linearly polarized with perpendicular polarization. For instance one horizontally polarized and the other vertically polarized. You can do polarization beam combining and just use a polarizer or a polarizing beamsplitter cube.

If the two lasers you want to combine share the same wavelength and the same polarization, and come from the same emitter they will interfere. This is coherent beam combining. In practice, for 2 lasers, you can use a beamsplitter to overlap the two lasers. The beamsplitter will have two outputs, you will need a way passive or active to lock the phase and ensure it is constructive interferences on the output of interest. For more than two lasers, you will need other methods to combine the beams.

Answer (score 0):

In theory yes, That is possible.

However, the laser does **NOT** stick together, the first beam will side to side with the second.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I guess this prism could work.
[image: prism image]